# Multiple users on same account meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am making an app that my company is going to use and I want the one account for each department, thus every employee from a certain department can log in and use that joint account. Can I just create an account with Meteor's account system or is it anything else I should think about?

Comment: Shared passwords are generally a terrible idea. Why not use oAuth and tie the app into your general login system? You can use roles for departments.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean you are going to have multiple humans share a password for an account, technically, yes that should work. Meteor supports multiple logins for a single account.

where you might run into trouble is multiple writes, e.g. if 2 people both decide to change the password.

however, just because it is technically possible, you might consider finding a way to fulfill your requirements but still allowing each human to have their own account.

for example, you could handle that with groups. each account is assigned to one or more groups, and each group shares data and functionality. if it is at all important to track who made a data change, this is a better approach.

the Meteor roles package (https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) could help in this regard.